# Data received from Websocket

Tags: angular, typescript, websocket

I am using Angular and trying to get data from the server using websocket. 
I am receiving the data from the server but when i try to use the data received it sends null instead of waiting for the server to send data.
Example:

```
this.wsService.createObservableSocket(environment.webSocketUrl).subscribe(data=>{
   console.log("data received !");
   this.messageFromServer = data;
});

//This happens before the data is received from the server.
// How do i make sure that this only occurs after data is received from server or
// whenever data is received from server

this.DoSomething(this.messageFromServer);
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `DoSomething()` only after data is received.

Try like this:

```
this.wsService.createObservableSocket(environment.webSocketUrl).subscribe(data=>{
  console.log("data received !");
  this.messageFromServer = data;
  this.DoSomething(this.messageFromServer);
});
```

Comment: I tried this but the problem is that i am using the data from server in some other component which gets run before this.Dosomething(this.messageFromServer) and gives me error.

Comment: If you have parent and child component, you can emit an event using `@Output()` once data is received, only then call `DoSomething()`